# Why I'm getting Flutter HTTP package error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the exact code example of Flutter's HTTP package with just different body contents, as in:

```
res = await http.post(
  Uri.parse("http://localhost:3000/login"),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    'email': "test@test.com",
    "password": "testPassword",
  }),
);
```

Yet I'm getting the error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` for the body format. And I can't leave the body without encoding to be a `Map<String, String>` because this will fail the API.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

jsonEncode outputs a String. You can just send a Map to your API.

Comment: The problem/point is that the docs of the HTTP package has an example that doesn't work out of the box. `post` method expects a Map while the code passes a String. This is aside, my backend doesn't accept a Map.

Comment: May I have a look at your API docs?

Comment: I didn't write docs for it. Just a Golang API that expects JSON (works with Postman). However I solved it by adjusting the API to start accepting Maps.